# Windows Batch File - Batch File stops executing after first command

Tags: batch-file

I created .bat file with the below commands but after first command executes .bat file closes!Where is the problem?

```
if not exist "C:\Users\pavle\AppData\Local\apktool\framework\1.apk" apktool if framework-res.apk
else del "C:\Users\pavle\AppData\Local\apktool\framework\1.apk"
if not exist "C:\Users\pavle\AppData\Local\apktool\framework\2.apk" apktool if twframework-res.apk
else del "C:\Users\pavle\AppData\Local\apktool\framework\2.apk"
apktool d SystemUI.apk
```

Comment: pause command didn't solve my problem!

Comment: please format and indent your code properly

Comment: I formatted it!

Comment: Illegal `if /?` syntax. Read the help or http://ss64.com/nt/if.html

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, I did not test though as I do not have the same environment.

```
if not exist "C:\Users\pavle\AppData\Local\apktool\framework\1.apk" (
       "apktool if framework-res.apk"
) else (
       del C:\Users\pavle\AppData\Local\apktool\framework\1.apk"
)
if not exist "C:\Users\pavle\AppData\Local\apktool\framework\2.apk" (
      "apktool if twframework-res.apk"
) else (
      "del "C:\Users\pavle\AppData\Local\apktool\framework\2.apk"
)
"apktool d SystemUI.apk"
```

Comment: It doesn't work!When I copy this code it even won't execute first line!!!

Comment: Are you running it from cmd line or did you create a batch file? What errors are you getting?

Comment: I created batch file and after first command executes I get "Framework successfully installed!

Comment: @pavlestojanovic Please put a pause at the end of the batch and run it. Edit the question an post the data.